# File & Folder Cake Php

Tags: cakephp

i have another problem with CakePhp concerning the File & Folder utility.
I am getting this error:

> Fatal Error Error: Call to undefined method
>   RegistriesController::clearStatCache()     File:
>   /var/www/crm0.convieneonline.it/lib/Cake/Utility/File.php  Line: 408

what i did it's simple:

1. I inserted App::uses('Folder', 'Utility'); and App::uses('File', 'Utility'); in the Controller
2. And then i developed the following code:

> ```
> $src = 'http://www.website.it/be/preventivatore/img/brands/'. $registry['Registry']['id'] .'.png';
>
> if ($check = File::exists($src)) {
>       $check = true;
>   } else {
>       $check = false;
>   }
> ```

Can you please help me with the error? Thank you

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: please try WWW_ROOT.'/img/brands/'.$registry['Registry']['id'] .'.png';

Comment: The CakePhp version is 2.5.8 . I will try your suggest Sharma, but i think is something different.Thank you